# What font is this? (Fantasy style font)

Tags: font-identification

I picked up this font a year or so ago. I thought I had written down what it was, but now I don't see it in my notes anywhere. I need it for a couple of projects, and I've been looking everywhere. Any ideas?

I have used every font identifier I could find doing a Google search. I'm using it for a current project but need it for similar projects.

[image: The]

Here are another few letters:

[image: ing]

Comment: You said you picked up this font; you mean the font file itself? Where are these images from?

Answer (score 2):

[Ayosmonika](https://www.fonts4free.net/ayosmonika-font.html) via fonts4free.net

[image: Ayosmonika]

This font is used in the JoyTurk Radio logo:

[image: JoyTurk]